# Mysql simple database design? (Quiz Contest)

Tags: c++, database-design

I am new to database design. This is my project:

Develop a simple quiz contest system for 1 month. After gather the information, following are the requirements:

Contestant:

- can take the contest given by the administrator
- can see the result

Administrator:

- Can create, modify, update and delete new Quiz. Each quiz consists of 20 questions
- Can create, modify, update and delete questions of specific quiz

I have designed a simple class diagram, see if this is a good practice:

Classes:

- Users Class (is a super class of Contestant and admin)

  Attributes: userid, username, password, type (contestant or admin)

  Methods: login()
- Contestants (subclass of Users)

  Methods: takeQuiz(), viewResult()
- Administrators (subclass of Users)

  Methods: CRUD methods of quiz and quetions()

Is that good enough? Should I create the Quiz and Questions Class?

My programming language is C++

Comment: This is not a specific question. Start implementing, then if you face difficulties, come back and post.

Comment: So far, i have no problems yet. The only thing I concern is, I think my current design is not very Object Oriented. Most of the functions are in the main.cpp file. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful:[c++ database tutorial](http://www.alhem.net/sql_cpp_tutorial/index.html)

and once you are done there,[database designer](http://www.alhem.net/dbdesigner/index.html)